# Get NSAttributed String color on tap (word color detect)

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

i am using NSAttributed String ,which contains multiple colors.Please check this image. [image]

I am selecting a word using TapGesture... For Example- i have selected "red"

```
- (void)tapGestureRecognizerHandle:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {

 SETextView *textView =  self.textV;

CGPoint location = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView: self.textV];
NSLog(@"Tap Gesture Coordinates: %.2f %.2f -- %@", location.x, location.y,textView.text);
 CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
//get location in text from textposition at point
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];


UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
 NSString *tappedSentence;
if (textRange != nil)
{
  tappedSentence = [textView textInRange:textRange];


 }

    else
{
    tappedSentence = textView.text;
}
}
```

**Now i want to know the color of selected word**
 any one have any idea please share

Thanks

Comment: You are use this label : https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: no Kirit... i am using simple textview with Tapgesture

Comment: @VarinderSingh SETextView is your own class or is it from library?

Comment: @RomanPodymov its a library .. https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SECoreTextView/tree/master/Lib

Answer (score 0):

found answer. **hope this will help Someone**

```
   textView.selectedTextRange=textRange;

NSRange oldRange = [self selectedRangeInTextView:textView];

NSAttributedString *selectedString = [textView.attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:oldRange];
[selectedString enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [selectedString length])
                                   options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
                                usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                                    UIColor *StringColor = [attributes objectForKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];


                                    self.backgroundColor=StringColor;

                                    if ([StringColor isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]]) {
                                        NSLog(@"blue Color");

                                    } else {
                                        NSLog(@"another Color");

                                    }
           }];
```

Comment: Tip: Use `enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:` instead looking only for `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, it makes the code clearer on your goal. Also, you may want to check if `stringColor` is nil or not.